# linked for loop doesn't increase the value of the counter

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

So basically I have a for loop in another for loop to go through two lists representing the rows of an Excel sheet. The problem however is, that the second for loop doesnt increase the value of the counter(current_row2 in the example). If i change the arrangement of the loops (increase current_row2 first and then go through the other sheet with current_row1) the one that didn't work now works and the other way around.
A few lines later i have another for loop to go through the columns of the Sheet. This loop works just fine.
I also tried using the for loop with range(max_rows) but it didn't work either.

Can someone help me why the problem occurs and how to fix it?

```
#row_list_ascending_no_doubles 1/2 / col_list... = [0,1,2,..,max_row1/2/col]
#signal_col is a constant value that represents the column with where i want to compare the values in
for current_row1 in row_list_ascending_no_doubles1:
    temp1 = str(df1.iloc[current_row1,signal_col1])
    for current_row2 in range(ro2):
        temp2 = str(df2.iloc[current_row2,signal_col2])
        if temp1 == temp2:
            for current_col in col_list_ascending_no_doubles:
                temp2 = str(df2.iloc[current_row2,current_col])
                temp1 = str(df1.iloc[current_row1,current_col])

                if temp1 == temp2:
                    print('cell equal')
                else:
                    print('not equal')
        break
```

Comment: Seems like your "break" should be inside the if statement right?otherwise you are constantly breaking your second loop after the first item

Comment: You unconditionally break out of the second loop after its first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code breaks before anything can happen. There is no `else` statement after `if temp1 == temp2` so it will hit the `break`  and stop the second for loop from running.